# MDI child window creation failing

Tags: c++, gdi+, win32gui

I have an MDI app, 2 different classes for the child windows. My problem is I can't create an instance of the 2nd if the first is already on screen, but I can do it the other way; if on case ID_OPEN_NEW in WndProc i change the class name to g_szChildClassName2, and then uncomment the contents of case WM_LBUTTONDOWN in MDIChildWndProc2 to create a child window of g_szChildClassName, then the 2 windows will create with no problem.

There's no error message, it just says the operation completed successfully. I imagine it's got something to do with the toolbar or the painting with GDI+.

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT iCmdShow)
{
    HWND                hWnd;
    MSG                 msg;
    WNDCLASSEXW         wc;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    g_instance = hInstance;

    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    if(!SetUpMDIChildWindowClass(hInstance))
        return 0;

    if(!SetUpMDIChildWindowClass2(hInstance))
        return 0;

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        g_szClassName,
        L"Interactive music",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 480, 320,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        if (!TranslateMDISysAccel(g_hMDIClient, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return msg.wParam;
} 

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, 
                         WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            CLIENTCREATESTRUCT ccs;
            ccs.idFirstChild = ID_MDI_FIRSTCHILD;

            g_hMDIClient = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"mdiclient", NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VISIBLE,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_MDI, GetModuleHandle(NULL), (LPVOID)&ccs);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_OPEN_NEW:
            {
                CreateNewMDIChild(g_hMDIClient, g_szChildClassName);
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                if(LOWORD(wParam) >= ID_MDI_FIRSTCHILD)
                {
                    DefFrameProc(hWnd, g_hMDIClient, WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
                }
                else 
                {
                    HWND hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(g_hMDIClient, WM_MDIGETACTIVE,0,0);
                    if(hChild)
                    {
                        SendMessage(hChild, WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefFrameProc(hWnd, g_hMDIClient, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MDIChildWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            g_hToolbar = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TOOL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
            if(g_hToolbar == NULL)
                MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not create tool bar.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

            HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_Create(22,22, ILC_COLORDDB, 4, 0);

            int what0 = ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(g_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_BITMAP2)), NULL);
            int what1 = ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(g_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_BITMAP3)), NULL);
            int what2 = ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(g_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_BITMAP1)), NULL);
            int what3 = ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(g_instance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_BITMAP4)), NULL);

            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_SETIMAGELIST, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)hImageList);

            TBBUTTON tbb[4] =   { 
                {what0, ID_NEW_STEP, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"CreateStep"},
                {what1, ID_DELETE_STEP, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"DeleteStep"},
                {what2, ID_NEW_SEGMENT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"CreateSegment"},
                {what3, ID_DELETE_SEGMENT, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)L"DeleteSegment"},
            };

            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, 4, (LPARAM)&tbb);
            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_SETBUTTONSIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM(22, 22));
            SendMessage(g_hToolbar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
            ShowWindow(g_hToolbar, SW_SHOW);

            g_MDIChildHwnd = hwnd;
            m_nHScrollPos = 0;
            SetUpMDIChildClientScrollbar();
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            OnPaint(hdc);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        {
            std::vector<CStep*>::iterator it = g_steps.begin();
            while(it!=g_steps.end())
            {
                CStep& step = **it;
                std::vector<CSegment*>::iterator its = step.m_segments.begin();
                while(its != step.m_segments.end())
                {
                    CSegment& seg = **its;
                    if(seg.m_bActive)
                    {
                        //create new window
                        CreateNewMDIChild(hwnd, g_szChildClassName2);
                        break;
                    }
                    its++;
                }
                it++;
            }
        }
    break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
            SetUpMDIChildClientScrollbar();
    default:
        return DefMDIChildProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MDIChildWndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            //CreateNewMDIChild(g_hMDIClient, g_szChildClassName);
        }
    default:
        return DefMDIChildProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

bool SetUpMDIChildWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = MDIChildWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);//(HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szChildClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Could Not Register Child Window", L"Oh Oh...",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

bool SetUpMDIChildWindowClass2(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = MDIChildWndProc2;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = NULL;//LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);//(HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szChildClassName2;
    wc.hIconSm       = NULL;//LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Could Not Register Child Window", L"Oh Oh...",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

HWND CreateNewMDIChild(HWND hMDIClient, const wchar_t* childClassName)
{ 
    MDICREATESTRUCT mcs;
    HWND hChild;

    mcs.szTitle = L"untitled";
    mcs.szClass = childClassName;
    mcs.hOwner  = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    mcs.x = mcs.cx = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mcs.y = mcs.cy = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mcs.style = WS_HSCROLL;

    hChild = (HWND)SendMessage(hMDIClient, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LONG)&mcs);
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    if(!hChild)
    {
        wchar_t buffer[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,dw,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),buffer,256,0);
        MessageBox(hMDIClient,buffer,L"Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    return hChild;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using the wrong handle, I was using hwnd when I should have used g_hMDIClient